# What happens if a demon lord is redeemed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

According to the description of [Scepter of Shibaxet](https://www.archivesofnethys.com/MagicArtifactsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Scepter%20of%20Shibaxet) (The weapon of the Kind of the Wind Demons, [Pazuzu](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-lords/demon-lord-pazuzu/)) a demon lord can be redeemed

> The Scepter of Shibaxet can be broken by a redeemed demon lord if the regenerating towers of Shibaxet are already destroyed.

The towers are his rookery, and can be found in his Abyssal plane.

But what happens after a demon lord is redeemed? Do they become gods or do they stay as demons or does something else altogether occur?

Comment: They become a _redeemon lord_.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The artifact in question is wielded by a CR 30 demigod... so the only Pathfinder AP that *might* feature him is Wrath of the Righteous. I'm not familiar with if he actually does show up in it, but it seems like this was more of a path to ask the question than a specific case.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The quote is actually from the description of the Artifact, as found at Archives of Nethys, or from the Bestiary.

Comment: @ifusaso I don't believe he is directly involved in any AP, but he is credited creating Deskari, who DOES feature in Wrath of the Righteous.

Comment: @YogoZuno Cool, thanks! No adventure events about those towers are being spoiled then, and no spoiler tags need to be edited in. That was my only concern. :)

Comment: Yeah I did want to bring that AP up because I think redeeming demons and/or devils is part of it. Someone familiar may be able to provide a strong answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It is unclear

As far as I'm aware there are no mechanics involving redemption specifically. The closest thing you could get is a Helm of Opposite Alignment followed by the Atonement spell (where the Helm allowed for the desire for repentance in the demon).

> This spell removes the burden of misdeeds from the subject. The creature seeking atonement must be truly repentant and desirous of setting right its misdeeds.

### What happens?

Demonhood is typically the destination for particularly sinful souls that arrive in the Abyss as larvae. Demon lords are simply demons that rose to the highest levels of power. If these demons had their origins as larvae they will likely return to their form as souls and be judged again fully atoned for. If a mortal managed to become a demon lord (as is the case with some), then the lord would probably return to their mortal form with their new alignment.

It is also easily possible that they would retain their current form albeit with the alignment change and other effects of Atonement.

Comment: I could also see them becoming celestials (probably angels) of a similar power level. In any event, firmly in the "GM fiat" category.

Comment: Actually, there ARE some concrete rules for Redemption, in Champions of Purity, but they are still a little wibbly-wobbly, and pretty much say they don't work for creatures with the Evil subtype.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no one "judges" them.

The universe places them there because it's where it thinks they belong.

And it's not about punishment.

It's just order.

Angels aren't naturally superior or more correct than demons in the eyes of the universe, just different.

So no you'd never lose any power or be put at someone else's whim for being redeemed.

So no they wouldn't be made mortal again or become weak souls again to be "judged"

What is most likely is they'd just stay physically as they are but be good.

Fiends and celestials can be whatever alignment they want, it's just their BODY that is good or evil.

That or they'd become celestial themed deities instead of infernal.

Comment: Hi Terror, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] if you haven't already to see how we work here. Do you have any text you can cite from Pathfinder sources to back up these claims?